# How does flow rate affect plume dynamics and film properties in PLD?

Tags: material-science, nanoscience

So I use a home-built Pulsed Laser Deposition(PLD) system to deposit metal oxide thin films. I use a $ 248\ \mathrm{nm KrF}$ laser. I recently deposited two films under slightly different conditions. In the first case, the oxygen flow rate was $0.5 \ \mathrm{sccm}$, turbo pump was off and only a rotary pump was sucking the oxygen out. In the second case, the oxygen flow rate was $10\ \mathrm{ sccm}$, turbo was on standby ($ 70\ \text{%}$) and the gate valve position was used to control the pressure. In both cases the chamber pressure during deposition was maintained at $\ \mathrm{50 mTorr}$. Peculiarly, I observed a wide egg shaped plume in the low flow condition and a narrow, bullet shaped plume in the high flow condition. In the first case, the film was poly crystalline with very low crystallinity and in the second, the film was amorphous. I am yet to test this more but I have a feeling that the complex oxide is undergoing some kind of a phase separation. Why should the flow rate affect the plume properties when the chamber pressure was kept same? If it helps, I use a small deposition chamber: it is a cylinder which is 6 inches in diameter and $15 \ \mathrm{inches}$ in length.

Comment: One point is the pressure gauge may not be measuring actual pressure at the target, depending on where it is relative to the pumps and valves.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

The height difference between the chamber and the pressure gauge (both are connected by a metal hose) is about 1.5 feet. So the error in pressure shouldn't be too high. Assuming that there is an error, it should be same for both cases, correct? So as long as the measured pressure is same, we can be quite certain that the chamber pressures are same.. so that gets us back to the original question..

Comment: Where are the pumps? A foot and a half of hose (what is the diameter?) could be big in terms of pressure difference.

Comment: I use a bellow pipe which is 25 mm in dia. How would that lead to big differences in pressure?